# Language equivalency for modified CFG closed over intersection

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, closure-properties

Suppose "CFG+" was created, where it is identical to standard context-free grammars in every way, but rather than rules being limited to unions, was also closed over intersections, both between CFGs and between other CFG+'s.

Consider non-context-free language:
$$
\{ a^nb^nc^n|n≥0\}
$$

With the addition of intersections, consider the following "CFG+":
$$
S\rightarrow AB\ \&\ CD
$$
$$
A\rightarrow aAb\ |\ \epsilon 
$$
$$
B\rightarrow cB\ |\ \epsilon
$$
$$
C\rightarrow aC\ |\ \epsilon
$$
$$
D\rightarrow bDc\ |\ \epsilon
$$

As AB covers when #a = #b, and CD when #b = #c, this intersection will match the non-context-free language given above.

It is obvious that context-free languages are a strict subset of the languages described by CFG+. However, how does this compare with other languages? Is this equivalent to a context sensitive grammar? An unrestricted grammar? Is there already a language category I should be recognizing this as?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like by describing your "CFG+" grammar, you have independently reinvented/rediscovered the [conjunctive grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_grammar).

Here is more quote from that article on Wikipedia.

> The family of conjunctive languages is closed under union, intersection, concatenation and Kleene star, but not under string homomorphism, prefix, suffix, and substring. Closure under complement and under $\epsilon$-free string homomorphism are still open problems.

Since context-sensitive languages are closed under complement, the family of conjunctive languages is a strict subset of the family of context-sensitive languages. In fact, the family of languages generated by [boolean grammars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_grammar), grammars that extends conjunction grammars with negation operations, is also a strict subset of the family of the context-sensitive languages.

---

A related problem is the expressive power of intersections of context-free languages.

[An infinite hierarchy of intersections of context-free languages](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01762237) by Liu and Weiner shows that ($d$-1)-intersection closure of context-free languages is strictly contained in the $d$-intersection closure of context-free languages, since the language $\{a_1^{n_1} a_2^{n_2} \cdots a_{d}^{n_{d}} b_1^{n_1} b_2^{n_2} \cdots b_d^{n_d} \mid n_1,n_2,\ldots ,n_d\ge 0\}$ is contained in the latter family of languages but not in the former family of languages for all $d\ge2$.

Answer (score 0):

Every such grammar will describe a context-sensitive language: every context-free language is also context-sensitive, and context-sensitive languages are closed under intersection.

I don't know if this describes a proper subset of the context-sensitive languages, or if every context-sensitive language can be formulated in this way.